# Fetching "card-title" html elements via cURL and parse/output response

Tags: php, android, ios, curl, debian

I need to monitor a website for any new items that are posted.

I used many RSS generators and viewers, but the sync interval is sub-par.

I figured I could simply cURL the page, when loaded, re-cURL.

Issue is, I have 0 experience with cURL.

I read the documentation.

I tried to use RSS generators, which works fine, but the sync interval is terrible or need to pay... and even then.

I need it to be as fast as possible. Lost last auction because of mere seconds.

```
<?php
$ch= curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://stackoverflow.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$output= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
<div class="content">
<pre>
   <?php
   echo htmlentities($output);
   ?>
</pre>
</div>
```

Using this code, I can fetch the page content.

What code should I add to output only "card-title" element?

P.S. I did not add the real link, but the page in question has item titles labeled as "card-title"

EDIT:
https://www.restockcrc.com/all/ (Only page one is necessary.)

PRTSCN: https://snag.gy/DnNMda.jpg

Comment: It's going to be pretty hard to help you without a link to the page so we can see then HTML structure

Comment: https://www.restockcrc.com/all/ (Only page one is necessary.) /// PRTSCN: https://snag.gy/DnNMda.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could grab the items, using regex. Ideally you want to parse the HTML rather than using regex, but unfortunately their HTML is not well formed.

```php
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.restockcrc.com/all/');

$re = '/<h4 class="card-title">.+?<a href="(\S+)">(.*?)<\/a>/ms';
preg_match_all($re, $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $item) {
    echo sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a><br>', $item[1], $item[2]); // Print results
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the code properly. Are regular expressions an accepted standard for HTML/PHP or do I need to do additional steps and "invoke" regex or something.

Comment: What do you mean? The `PCRE` regex engine is built into PHP. You should be able to run the code above and show the results?

Comment: https://snag.gy/hQCRDN.jpg > That's what I get. I tried clicking "fork" but it just creates another pattern.

Comment: Works, you're an Archwizard, Aty.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it fixed :)

Comment: If by any chance, you have some code to programatically use this php script and do an action when/if the first line of the output changes. (E.g. Notification, SMS API calls, etc), you'd be the BEST arch-mage of this cursed land, Harry.

Comment: Let's continue this in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197132/fetching-card-title-html-elements-via-curl-and-parse-output-response)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Need 20 points to chat. I got +2 atm. I'm at 20 now. I did not have access to the chat. Also, how do I use it??

Comment: Saves us comment here where's it's clogging up the post :)